# How to allow users from other computers to connect to my IIS7 website?

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to run a website in IIS7 for testing purposes. I can coonnect to it from my local pc typing http://localhost/Webpage1/Default.aspx   (or http://localhost to open the default IIS starting page), but i can't connect to it from other computers. 
In other similar topics suggestions was to change hosts file in c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc, but something is not working for me.
Can you please tell me what exactly should i write there and how to connect, if my IP address is 80.233.186.188?
Thanks, Walt

Comment: Why don't you just connect to [http://80.233.186.188/](http://80.233.186.188/) ?

Comment: I tried that and it couldnt connect to it.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall / router and need to direct traffic from outside your network?  Can you access it from another PC on your network using your internal network IP address?

Comment: Are the other computers on the same network as you?  I'm guessing this is a NAT'ing issue and probably not going to be answered on SO.

Comment: I have a router and i'm trying to connect from other computer that is not in my network. So i should leave hosts file as it was before and look for problem somewhere else (firewall, or something)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you developed this using WebMatrix. That installs IIS 7 Express, instead of IIS 7. It happened to me too, and I solved the problem by following the steps here: http://blog.alirobertson.com/post/11139712138/enabling-non-localhost-access-to-webmatrix