# How to allow access to internal website in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I developed my first website for a simple internal application using Webmatrix in a Windows 2008 Server R2 machine.
I'm able to open the site with a browser in the same machine as it is running, but cannot open it from any other machine in the network. I cannot open the default IIS7 website either.

The error is **401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials**.

This is what I have done so far, without any changes in the results:

- Changed the port of my site to 80, and the default to 8080
- Where it lists all the sites (so far just the default and mine), right-clicked on my site, selected `Edit Permissions`, selected the `Security` tab, and verified that `Everyone` has `Allow` permissions for everything
- Where it lists all the sites (so far just the default and mine), right-clicked on my site, selected `Edit Permissions`, selected the `Security` tab, and added `Domain Users` with `Read & execute`, `List folder contents` and `Read` permissions.

BTW, this fellow seem to have the same problem and there were no answers: [How to allow users from other computers to connect to my IIS7 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589759/how-to-allow-users-from-other-computers-to-connect-to-my-iis7-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [Enabling Non Localhost access to WebMatrix](http://blog.alirobertson.com/post/11139712138/enabling-non-localhost-access-to-webmatrix)